# In r, assigning the previous non na value

Tags: r, zoo, na

I need to fill forward the NA values, that is, replace NA with the last previous non NA value.  Here is an example, but the last line doesn't fill forward.  I get an error that the number of values to be replaced is different than the number of replacement values.  What am I doing wrong?

```
# Test time accumulation and assignment
foo_df <- NULL
nTimes = 10000
nEvents = 70
nUnits = 300
usageTimes = seq(0.5, 3, .5)
events = c("File Event", paste("Event ",seq(1,nEvents)))
randDates <- function(N, st="2014/01/01", et="2014/07/31") {
     st <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(st))
     et <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(et))
     dt <- as.numeric(difftime(et,st,unit="sec"))
     ev <- sort(runif(N, 0, dt))
     rt <- st + ev
}
probEvent = rep(1, length(events))
probEvent[1] = 5
# Generate fake data with events, units, and event times
foo_df = data.frame(eventName = sample(events, nTimes, replace=T, probEvent),
   unit = sample(seq(1,nUnits),nTimes,replace=T),
   event_time= randDates(nTimes),
   usageTime = NA, cumTime=NA)
# Order by time, and set the first nUnits events to File Event for each unit
foo_df = foo_df[with(foo_df, order(event_time)), ]
foo_df[1:nUnits ]$eventName = "File Event"
foo_df[1:nUnits ]$unit = seq(1,nUnits)
# Add random usage times to File Events
nFile = length(foo_df$eventName[foo_df$eventName == "File Event"])
foo_df$usageTime[foo_df$eventName == "File Event"] = sample(usageTimes, nFile, replace=T)
# Order by unit / event time
foo_df = foo_df[with(foo_df, order(unit,event_time)), ]

# accumulate the event time for file events
entire_file_rows = foo_df$eventName=="File Event"
temp_df = data.frame(cum_ft=0, event_time=foo_df$event_time[entire_file_rows],
      unit=foo_df$unit[entire_file_rows], usageTime=foo_df$usageTime[entire_file_rows])
temp_df$cumTime <- ave(temp_df$usageTime, temp_df$unit, FUN=cumsum) 
foo_df$cumTime[entire_file_rows] = temp_df$cumTime

# This is where I'm stuck
# Want to assign the cummulative time to the other events (non File Event)

library(zoo) ; 
# foo_df[foo_df$eventType != "File Event"]$"cumTime" <- NA 
foo_df$cumTime <- na.locf(foo_df$cumTime)
```

I get the error message: "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "cumTime", value = c(2.5, 2.5, 4, 4,  : 
  replacement has 9993 rows, data has 10000"

I can see that there are two problems, first, the NA occur first, so they don't get carried from na.locf, and second, the locf should be grouped on unit.

But, why do the NA occur first?  THe data was sorted based on EventTime, then the first nUnit records were assigned unit numbers 1 to nUnit, and eventName "File Event".  How can later, when sorted by unit and eventTime, there be times before the "File Event" records?

This process is supposed to accumulate the usage time in cumTime, with the record ordered by unit and then EventTime.  Before transfering the cumTIme from "File Event" to other events, I plot the cumTime grouped by unit and event type vs eventTime, and that plot looks ok, cumTime is increasing.  But, after transferring the cumTime from "File Event" to the other events, then the plot of cumTime (grouped by unit / event type) vs eventTime is not correct because the cumTime has spikes and gradual decreasing values, which isn't possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem that you have leading `NA` values.  These are removed by default in `na.locf` leading to a short vector on the right-hand side of the assignment.

You can assign with the leading `NA`'s:

```
foo_df$cumTime <- na.locf(foo_df$cumTime, na.rm=FALSE)
```

This will overwrite every `NA` value except the leading values.

Then you can assign the leading `NA` values to something else:

```
foo_df$cumTime[is.na(foo_df$cumTime)] <- 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Once I group by unit, which I overlooked, then if there are leading NA, it makes sense to do na.locf in reverse.  How do I group by unit?

Comment: or try `na.fill(na.locf(...whatever...), 0)`

Comment: Shoot, I didn't ask the question well enough.  Can you read the expanded question, and then try to modify your answer.  In the "real" data, the cummulatated time can decrease with passage of event time, which isn't possible, and I think the error is in the sorting by unit / event time, which may be the same error that is causing the leading na in this example (which shouldn't occur).

Comment: @Matthew Lundberg  Since the data was sorted by eventTime, and the first nUnit records assigned nunits and "File Event", how is possible that there are records before the "File Event" when sorting by unit and eventTime?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the lines assigning the "File Event" and unit to the the first nUnits records.  The correct lines are

```
foo_df$eventName[1:nUnits ] = "File Event"
foo_df$unit[1:nUnits ] = seq(1,nUnits)
```

Then, there isn't a problem with the first lines not having a usage time, and the command na.locf(foo_df$cumTime) generates the correct number of records.